# Using fragments: Having a couple of issues

Tags: android, android-fragments

I do iOS development for my company and built our main mobile app which is used at our conferences. Building the android app was initially outsourced and because it was too expensive to include all the iOS features of the app I wrote, we went with a basic android shell and made use of lots of webviews which we also utilized in our mobile web app (HTML5).

Due to budget constraints, all android development on the app is now my responsibility. I have very little experience with java/android OS but I am learning pretty quickly. I successfully included pulling data from a web service, storing it in SQLite and using it to populate a list in the app using an activity, which was not present in the app initially (I'm trying to move away from webviews). However, I realize that most of the functionality in the app is built using fragments. When I try to convert the activity to a fragment I am running into problems. The code is below.

I am having issues with the method:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

The error is "`This method must return a result of type View.`"

In my displayListView() method, I am getting errors in these two lines:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
```

The error is "`The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type EhallSchedFragment2`".

The full code in the fragment is below:

```
package org.bicsi.canada2014.fragment;

import java.util.List;
import org.bicsi.fall2014.R;
import org.bicsi.canada2014.adapter.SQLiteDB;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;

public class EhallSchedFragment2 extends Fragment{
    public static final String TAG = "ExHallScheduleFragment";
    private SQLiteDB sqlite_obj;
     List<String> list1, list2, list3, list4;
     private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ehschedule, container, false);

        sqlite_obj = new SQLiteDB(getActivity());

        displayListView();

    }

     private void displayListView(){

        sqlite_obj.open();

         Cursor cursor = sqlite_obj.fetchAllSchedules();

         // The desired columns to be bound
         String[] columns = new String[] {
           SQLiteDB.KEY_SCHEDULEDATE,
           SQLiteDB.KEY_SESSIONNAME,
           SQLiteDB.KEY_SESSIONTIME

         };

         // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
         int[] to = new int[] { 
           R.id.textViewScheduleDate,
           R.id.textViewSessionName,
           R.id.textViewSessionTime,

         };

         // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
         //as well as the layout information
         dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                 getActivity(), R.layout.schedule_info, 
                   cursor, 
                   columns, 
                   to,
                   0);

         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         // Assign adapter to ListView
         listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

         EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
          myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           }

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int count, int after) {
           }

           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
             int before, int count) {
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
           }
          });

          dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                 public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                     return sqlite_obj.fetchScheduleByDate(constraint.toString());
                 }
             });
    }

}
```

Comment: I would also consider using a ListFragment instead of the base Fragment class. A ListFragment is designed to be used with lists as the name suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment's **onCreateView** method, the signature of that method indicates that you must return a view like this:

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ehschedule, container, false);

    sqlite_obj = new SQLiteDB(getActivity());

    displayListView();

    return v;

}
```

To access components in your fragment's layout file (like list views and such), you have to first of all cast it to the respective type and then call findViewById on the view like this:

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ehschedule, container, false);

       Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);

       //always return a view last. A return statement in Java comes last.
       return v;

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First You have to return a View of your Fragment layout on **onCreateView** . second you are inflating your layout in onCreateView so your function doesn't know anything about your layout, you have to initialize your Fragment content by the view which inflated on onCreateView :

```
ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Comment: I think I am returning a View of the fragment layout: View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ehschedule, container, false);. My fragment layout is fragment_ehschedule. I think because the onCreateView method is outside of my displayListView() method when I add the line above for ListView, I am getting "v cannot be resolved."

Comment: @bachma0507 : no there is no view returned from your onCreateView. you have to return like return v; in your onCreateView()